# Backup of VisualSVN

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, svn, visualsvn-server

I've got installed a VisualSVN in a Windows Server 2003 (it has just a 
drive C: with 10GB)

I'm planning to backup a VisualSVN server in this way:

- Make a disk image with Ghost or some other software of my Windows 
  Server 2003.
- Every night make a copy of the whole folder: 'C:\Repositories'
- If I upgrade VisualSVN version, I should make again other disk 
  image.

In case of disaster recovery, in order to restore server, I would only 
need to:

- Restore Ghost image in a new server
- Paste folder 'C:\Repositories' from backup to new server

My question are:

- Would it work?
- Is 'C:\Repositories' the only folder that I have to backup? Do I 
  have to backup any other thing?

Thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/407493/107134

Comment: FYI: the server now includes a built-in [backup and restore feature](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work the way you describe. You really only need to back up your repositories folder, though. Re-installing VisualSVN is easy, even on another server, and you can just copy the repositories folder on top after you do that.

It might be simplest to use NTBACKUP for this on Win2003, with nightly incrementals or differentials. Or use whatver other backup software you already use at your company, or the cloud backup service of your choice. There's nothing special about SVN repositories, they're just files.

There is a caveat, in that if you back up an SVN repository that is being committed to *during the backup*, you can in rare circumstances get a corrupt repository. The repository can be easily repaired with [`svnadmin recover`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.recover.html) command though.

Using NTBACKUP or some other backup tool that is Volume ShadowCopy aware will "snapshot" the whole drive ensuring a clean backup